# Table with one unique value from a Unique ID in PowerBI

Tags: statistics, powerbi, data-visualization, dax

I will need some help calculating or extracting a data for Power BI. I thought using either Dax or Power BI query, but cannot get what I am looking for.

I have a lot of data from a webanalytics tool, for each line I have a unique ID (ID_Visit), a unique client ID (ID_Client), a datetime (date_ID) & an average number of page per visit (Page_Av). For each unique ID I already have the mean of average page per unique ID, how can I get only one line per dateid and ID visit ?

My table is like that

[image]

What I would like is unique value like this

- C1 <=> 3
- C2 <=> 2
- C3 <=> 7

For Power BI, it will be displayed like this :

[image]

I tried with `Groubby` function ; but it does not work for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the query editor and add a blank query. Refer this blank query to your raw data:

[image]

Group by your two columns ID_Client and Page_Av:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. Have a nice and pleasant day!

Answer (score 1):

If all you are looking for is to display this information in a chart, then you can directly use the table in the chart. If you are going with a bar chart:

1. Put ID_Client in the Axis
2. Move Page_Av to the Values space
3. Click on the small down arrow next to Page_Av in the values space
4. You can select a summarizing option from here
5. For your scenario max/min/avg would work

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @CR7SMS
It works well, my goal was to display a mean of each ID_Client